# Product of PSD matrices is not PSD?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A and B are PSD matrices, then AB is not always a PSD matrix? Since A is PSD, then there exists an unique PSD square root  $A^{1/2}$. So $AB=A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B$. Since eign values of $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B$= eign values of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ and also eign values of  $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ are $\geq 0$ since $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is PSD, which implies eign values of $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B$ are $ \geq 0$. Therefore $AB$ is PSD. There is a mistake in the proof, I don't know where is the mistake.

Comment: Why are the eigen values of $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B$ the same as the one from $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ ? For me, the trace is the same but not the eigen value.

Comment: Since eign values of $XY$ = eign values of $YX$. In this case $X=A^{1/2}$, $B=A^{1/2}B$

Comment: This is not true in general, see the example below.

Answer (score 3):

**Counter example**

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\succ 0\\B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\succ 0$$but$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\2&-3\end{bmatrix}\prec0$$

Comment: How is AB not PD? Per Sylvester's criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), the top left 1x1 matrix has determinant 1 (>0) and the top left 2x2 matrix has determinant 1(-3) - (-2)2 = -3 +4 = 1 (>0). What am I missing?

Comment: This is because $AB$ is not hermitian, i.e. $(AB)^H\ne AB$